# Using TabLayout inside a Fragment; tab text invisible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-support-design

I'm currently experimenting with various new components in the new [Android Support Design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). I've implemented a `NavigationView` in my `MainActivity.java`, which uses a FragmentManager to navigate between the items in the Navigation drawer:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content, mTabLayoutFragment)
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    .commit();
```

I'm using a `TabLayout` in one of the fragments. Here is the fragment's layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And the Java code behind it:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.*;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabLayoutFragment extends Fragment {   


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tablayout, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Campusplan"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Raumplan"));
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter
                (getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return inflatedView;
    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int mNumOfTabs;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    TabItem1 tab1 = new TabItem1();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    TabItem1 tab2 = new TabItem1();
                    return tab2;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note `TabItem1` and `TabItem1`, which are fragments consisting of nothing but a TextView. These two are to be displayed in the TabLayout.

Now, this code seems to be working, to some extent. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

What's weird is, after I **rotate** the device, everything seems to be working just fine:

[image]

It seems like something gets called upon a configuration change. This is weird, especially considering that I have following in my `AndroidManifest`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Update:
This was due to a bug in the design library 22.2.1. Using 23.0.0 solves this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I face the same problem with new version of android support Design Library v23.1.1. But I just figure it out what happening.

if your view pager has 2 fragment as your mention above, then you set your view pager with this statement:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**automatically you will have 2 tabs** with empty text. **So you should not add new tab anymore**. But something you have to do is to **set text in that two created tabs.**

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Campusplan");
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Raumplan");
```

**Conclusion**. To make tabs work as you want,  important thing you have to do :

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Campusplan");
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Raumplan");
```

I hope this will be helpful for you :)

Comment: This is correct answear for me. As mentioned above works for support Design Library 23.1.1. Thank you:)

Comment: but why this will not work?tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Campusplan"));
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Raumplan"));

Comment: @abh22ishek as far as I know, like my explanation above. When you set viewpager inside tabLayout, the tablayout automatically add a number of tabs depends on number of viewpager's fragment you have. So when you use this statememnt: 
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Campusplan")); 

you add a new tab with empty fragment. CMIIW

Answer (score 19):

**Update:** Design Library v23.0.0 solves this issue.

---

Found the problem here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180462

Simple workaround:

```
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
});
```

Comment: The tabs now are ok, but sometimes when I change between the Navigation drawer items, the inner fragment of this `TabLayout` disappear. Do you have your code on github to look at?

Comment: thank you, I was using `getActivity().getSupportFragment()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: compiling design library **v23.0.1** made me gradle execution error with **empty error message**, but the **code workaroud working fine**, thanks.

Comment: Is it recommended that we put the ViewPager inside an AppBarLayout if we are working with a TabLayout attached to our Toolbar or it doesn't matter where you put the viewpager in the xml layouts?

Answer (score 5):

just tried to override the method in adapter:

`public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {}`

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The developer working on this library recommends the following work-a-round:

```
if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(tabLayout)) {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    } else {
        tabLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                tabLayout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lack reputation to comment @arif ardiansyah...

Check the source code:

```
 `TabLayout#setupWithViewPager(...)` 

 -->>`setPagerAdapter(adapter, true);`

 -->>`populateFromPagerAdapter();`
```

Here, `TabLayout` removes all tabs and recreates some new tabs whose text are set with `PagerAdapter#getPageTitle(...)`. So you can override this method to provide `Tablayout` with your tabs' title.