# Problems replacing an android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, android-tablayout

**What I have:**

I am using the latest Android support and design libraries on API 22. I have a fragment called **ProgressFragment** which I ***only run when my app is first installed*** as follows:

```
mProgressFragment = new ProgressFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, mProgressFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT)
                .commit();
```

This is the layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/progress_frag"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/build_lib_progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/progress_msg1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_primary"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/progress_msg2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_secondary"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This fragment contains an **AsyncTask**. When it completes, it is replaced by another fragment (called **MainFragment**) in **MainActivity** inside the AsyncTask callback **onPostExecute()** like so:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
```

This is the **MainFragment** layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/main_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_appbar_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

And this is MainActivity's layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Main content displayed here -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Navigation Drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_view_menu"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/text_tertiary"
    app:itemIconTint="#8b8b8b"
    />
```

**The Problem:**

When the AsyncTask in ProgressFragment completes and is replaced by MainFragment, the **TabLayout** view does not display tabs:

[image]

My application has 2 possible paths at startup. It either:

1. Adds the ProgressFragment (if first run) -> then replaced by MainFragment
2. Adds MainFragment otherwise (tabs show up fine here)

Both Fragment replacements happen in MainActivity.

The problem deals with path 1

**EDIT 2:**

Calling **recreate()** in MainActivity "fixes" this for now. Though I wouldn't call it a solution. Will come back to it later.

Comment: Where is ProgressFragment being added from?

Comment: onCreate() in MainActivity. Its layout contains a FrameLayout with id "main_container" which I replace with a ProgressFragment or MainFragment depending if it's the first time the app has been run.

Comment: Please post MainActivity layout as well

Comment: Added MainActivity's layout in edit

Comment: Logic looks pretty good, a couple things to try to narrow it down:

Comment: I'd dig into specific reasons why the tabs wouldn't show up. What's the data source for the tabs and what state is it in?

Comment: MainFragment itself contains a viewpager and uses a custom adapter that extends **FragmentPagerAdapter**. The adapter is created and set in MainFragment's onCreateView().

Comment: Added edit 2. Will stick with that for now while I find a better solution.

Comment: take a look here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641979/using-tablayout-inside-a-fragment-tab-text-invisible][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641979/using-tablayout-inside-a-fragment-tab-text-invisible

Comment: Did the answer solved your question, if it did please mark it as right, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It was a bug on v22.2.1, solved on newer releases

Found the problem here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180462

Simple workaround:

```
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
});
```