# ViewPager and FrameLayout together

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-framelayout

I cannot find sensible information on that matter so maybe I am doing it completely wrong?

I am trying to use a `Navigation Drawer` with a `FrameLayout` to display `fragments`.

However, when clicking one of the items on the Drawer, I would like to display a `TabLayout` with 3 fragments

So what architecture do I need to use?

Should the Activity inflating the drawerlayout host the `ViewPager` and the `FrameLayout`?

So clicking on Settings on the drawer for example the `FrameLayout`displays a settings fragment but when hitting Events, a fragment with 3 Tabs showing different events appear inside the `FrameLayout`?

Or should I hide the framelayout somehow then and display the `ViewPager` inside the Activity?

The main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabCapsFalse"
            android:background="@color/teal"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/iron"

            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tealfifty"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/purple600"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/tealfifty"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_items" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you gave me a link to that answer but about the activity: When I run my App I get to the MainActivity which controls the Drawer and all fragments(different parts of the app). However, the first thing that it has to show is exactly the ViewPager+TabLayout. So you suggest that I have one activity with the drawer and only the viewpager with the 3 tabs, no framelayout? And in case the user navigates away from the events shown in the ViewPager, he goes to the other activity which holds another drawer with a framelayout, and now this activity controls the content of the whole app?

Comment: If the tabs are the first thing the user sees, then that changes it a bit.  If your minsdk is 17 or greater, or you use support library Fragments, you can do it with nested Fragments. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641979/using-tablayout-inside-a-fragment-tab-text-invisible

Comment: One of my attempts was using nested fragments I believe but maybe I got it wrong. Do you care to elaborate please and maybe provide a relevant link? In terms of the architecture of the whole app I mean since that's my main problem, integrate all the Drawer+FrameLayout to manage different sections of my app and then having a TabLayout as well (which also opens as the first visible thing to the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having a MainActivity with a DrawerLayout and FrameLayout to display fragments. One of the fragments is a HostFragment for my 3 TabLayout Fragments that I am to display. The ViewPager is in the HostFragment layout as a single element. The setup of ViewPager and TabLayout is done in the HostFragment as well.

**This is my DrawerLayout**:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    layout="@layout/appbar_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/tealfifty"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**appbar_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/teal"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/purple800"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tabicons"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tealfifty"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabCapsFalse"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/iron" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="@layout/appbar_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/addico"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/content_main_frame"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

One of my main problems was that I was using just a `FrameLayout`, or just a `NestedScrollView`. Now that I put the latter inside the `FrameLayout` and I gave the `FrameLayout` a `scroll_behaviour`, I guess the `ScrollView` inherits it and everything works like a charm! It took me a very long time to come to the conclusion how to set this up!

Answer (score 0):

You want each section in the `Drawer` to navigate to a new `Fragment`. Since the `TabLayout` is only going to be on one of the screens, it will go in one of the `Fragments` called by your `Activity`. For example, remove the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` from activity_main.xml, and put them in a new fragment instead. Add that `Fragment` to `content_frame`, and you're all set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/tealfifty"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_items" />
```

Comment: I am going to try that again as I implemented it previously and faced problems so I experimented with my example above. I'm wondering, the viewpager and tablayout would be in lets say ExampleFragment, what should I do for it's layout, should it just contain the viewpager and tablayout so that it is like a host fragment, and then in the TabLayout I add another 3 fragments, cause right now I have an ExampleFragment with a recycler view and the viewpager and tablayout, and then in the tablayout I also add an instance of that same ExampleFragment as the first item

Comment: You don't need to add `Fragments` to the `TabLayout` in xml, they get set programmatically. http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: i am setting them programmatically, that's what i meant sorry. I have a fragment setting 3 other fragments programmatically to the viewpager. However, right now the first fragment added to the viewpager is the host fragment itself with the newinstance method